# Indicativo vs subjuntivo con "después de que"

Tags: subjuntivo

Dos acciones están en perspectiva de un momento pasado ¿no? ¿Alguien me podría explicar por favor por qué en (1) se usa el indicativo mientras en la frase (2) se utiliza el subjuntivo?

(1) *Pues esto ocurrió **después de que ella lo interrumpió en su lectura de la tarde** para pedirle que la mirara a la cara, y él tuvo el primer indicio de que su círculo infernal había sido descubierto.*

(2) *La prima Hildebranda Sánchez había venido a visitarla poco **después de que ella estuviera en su hacienda de Flores de María** reponiéndose de la mala hora de la señorita Lynch.*

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tenemos en (1) algo que definitivamente ocurrió cronológicamente después de la interrupción.  Ella lo interrumpió y «esto» (lo que fuese) ocurrió.

Pero en (2), algo vino *con el fin* de visitar a alguien después de otra acción.  No tenemos certeza de que ella estuviera allí ni, en el caso de que así fuera, de que llegasen después del hecho.  Puede que hubiesen llegado antes aunque si intención fuese el contrario.

Si usásemos el indicativo en (2), en vez de decir que la intención era llegar visitar después de aquello, estaríamos diciendo meramente el orden cronológico: ella estaba allí, y algo antes alguien vino a visitarla.

Comment: Yo no estoy de acuerdo: por una parte, sí se tiene la certeza de que estuviera allí; y, por otra, en nada se puede suponer que haya sido su intención. Puede ser una cuestión de duración: decir "ocurrió después de que lo _interrumpiera_" suena raro porque interrumpir es algo inmediato. De la misma manera,  "poco después de que _estuvo_ en..." también porque se trata de una acción que evidentemente lleva tiempo. Podría haber dicho "poco después de que _estaba_ en su hacienda", evitando así el subjuntivo, pero (no me preguntes por qué) el indicativo sólo parece funcionar aquí en pasado perfecto.

Comment: @Yay Vamos a hacerlo algo más abstracto: «vine a casa a hacer X después de Y».  Si mi intención era que X siguiera Y, se usa subjuntivo porque al momento de mi llegada, Y todavía se habría ocurrido.  Ahora bien, si vine después de Y a hacer X, es decir, X no depende de Y, se usa indicativo porque habría sido mi llegada que dependió de Y, y entonces al momento de mi llegada, Y ya habría ocurrido.

Comment: «interrumpiera» puede tener valor perfectivo (1) en algunos dialectos en los cuales ambas formas del pretérito perfecto del subjuntivo adquieren ese valor en cláusulas como estas (es decir, *interrumpiera/se* == *hubiera/se interrumpido*) y (2) en algunos dialectos y en la lengua literaria que permiten usar las formas *-ra* como pluscuamperfecto simple, pero solo en el indicativo (es decir, *interrumpiera* == *había interrumpido*)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, pero, si te he entendido bien, fíjate que con ello me das la razón: "vine a casa después de que Juan se fue" no expresa intención; "vine a casa después de que Juan se fuera", sí. Pero esto no aplica a acciones de larga duración: "vine a casa después de que Juan estuvo una hora viendo la tele" no tiene sentido -o cuanto menos suena extraño. Aquí se debe utilizar el subjuntivo ("vine a casa después de que Juan estuviese/haya estado una hora viendo la tele"), y no por ello se expresa necesariamente finalidad, aunque sea simplemente porque no hay otra forma de decirlo.

Comment: Para mi la primera frase no tiene sentido, está mal formada.